# How can I rewrite a multi-column IN clause to work on SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I've got a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table
WHERE
  (col1, col2) in (
    ('col1_val1', 'col2_val1'),
    ('col1_val2', 'col2_val2'),
    ('col1_val3', 'col2_val3'),
  )
```

This works in MySQL, but fails in sqlite3 with a syntax error:

```
Error: near ",": syntax error
```

How can I rewrite this query to an equivalent one that works in sqlite3?

Comment: Most SQL dialects don't support that.  Are those implicit ANDs or ORs?

Comment: I know most SQL dialects don't support it; that's why I want to rewrite it. It means basically `WHERE (col1 = 'col1_val1' AND col2 = 'col2_val1') OR (col1 = 'col1_val2' AND col2 = 'col2_val2') OR...`

Comment: Short of doing what you just wrote in the comment, I'd probably be looking at creating a temporary table and doing a multi-column JOIN to get the rows you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Choose your favourite version:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6169b/9

### using temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pair (a INTEGER, b INTEGER);
INSERT INTO pair (a, b) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO pair (a, b) VALUES (2, 2);
....
```

data IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is not unique

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM  pair
  WHERE pair.a = data.a
    AND pair.b = data.b
);
```

data IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is unique

```
SELECT     data.*
FROM       data
INNER JOIN pair
        ON pair.a = data.a
       AND pair.b = data.b;
```

data NOT IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is unique

```
SELECT    data.*
FROM      data
LEFT JOIN pair
   ON pair.a = data.a
  AND pair.b = data.b
WHERE pair.a IS NULL
   OR pair.b IS NULL;
```

### using inline table

data IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is not unique

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL
  FROM  (
    SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS a, 3 AS b
  ) AS pair
  WHERE pair.a = data.a
    AND pair.b = data.b
);
```

data IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is unique

```
SELECT     data.*
FROM       data
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS a, 3 AS b
) AS pair
 ON  pair.a = data.a
AND  pair.b = data.b;
```

data NOT IN pairs; if pair(a,b) is unique

```
SELECT    data.*
FROM      data
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 1 AS b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS a, 3 AS b
 ) AS pair
   ON pair.a = data.a
  AND pair.b = data.b
WHERE pair.a IS NULL
   OR pair.b IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's an easy solution that works, but it might not perform well on large data sets because it can't use any of your indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col1 || '-' || col2 in (
  'col1_val1-col2_val1',
  'col1_val2-col2_val2',
  'col1_val3-col2_val3'
)
```

[Try it in sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c768d/1)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 8):

In sqlite try to add the VALUES keyword:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
  (col1, col2) in ( VALUES     --> add this keyword and remove the last ,
    ('col1_val1', 'col2_val1'),
    ('col1_val2', 'col2_val2'),
    ('col1_val3', 'col2_val3')
  )
```

Basically in sqLite executing the query:

```
VALUES
('col1_val1', 'col2_val1'),
('col1_val2', 'col2_val2');
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT 'col1_val1' AS column1, 'col2_val1' AS column2
UNION 
SELECT 'col1_val2' AS column1, 'col2_val2' AS column2;
```

or combined:

```
SELECT 'col1_val1' AS column1, 'col2_val1' AS column2
UNION  VALUES  ('col1_val2', 'col2_val2');
```

So you could even write it like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
  WHERE (col1, col2) IN ( 
      SELECT 'col1_val1', 'col2_val1'
      UNION 
      SELECT 'col1_val2', 'col2_val2'
  );
```

which is a simple subquery and works in all/most databases.

Comment: For Android devs - beware, the first option with "VALUES" doesn't work on Android 7. Probably because of outdated sqlite.