# insert new rows and delete old rows if not in the list.

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to model a relationship between two tables TableA and TableB.
The relationships are listed in their own table RelationTable with columns: ID, tableA_ID, tableB_ID.

To make sure each combination of TableA_ID and TableB_ID is unique, I added a "unique (tableA_ID,tableB_ID)" in the "create Table" statement.

In addition, each row in the RelationTable can belong to a group (in the GroupTable with columns ID and groupName).

Now I want to update my RelationTable. I have an update list of matching rowID's of TableA and TableB. I also know the group to which these pairs belong.

I can insert new row's and ignore the insert if the row exist.

```
insert or ignore into RelationTable (tableB_ID,tableB_ID) values (:a,:b)
```

Then I fetch the insertedRowID and add it to the GroupTable. (though perhaps these two steps can be done in 1 step, and with batch updates?)

But how do I delete the rows in RelationTable (and GroupTable) that are no longer valid? The invalid rows are the rows whose (tableA_ID, tableB_ID) pair are not in the update/(or active relationships) list but which are listed in the GroupTable.

I am stuck on this statement. It doesn't take into account the groupTable and I have to union every pair of values. That is probably fine for a small number of pairs, but it gets unwieldy for a larger number. Is this the way forward?

```
delete from RelationTable where ID not in 
  (select RelationTable from RelationTable inner join 
    (select "aValue"      as a, "aValue2" as b union all 
     select "anotherValue as a, "anotherValue2" as b
    ) as pair 
   on pair.a = RelationTable.tableA_ID and 
      pair.b = RelationTable.tableB_ID
   )
```

[Inspiration for the last statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525779/how-can-i-rewrite-a-multi-column-in-clause-to-work-on-sqlite)

Comment: What is the update list?

Comment: The update list is an array of rowID's (destinations). Each list has an associated source. Example list1: row 11 of tableB points to rows 2,4,7 of tableA / List2: row 2 of tableA points to row 11 of tableB / etc.

Comment: why don't you empty your relation table (DELETE FROM RelationTable) before inserting new elements ?