# How to select rows matching multiple columns from a list of tuples?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a collection with the following values:

```
[
  {number: 7, letter: 'T'},
  {number: 2, letter: 'R'},
  {number: 4, letter: 'T'}
]
```

and a table with the columns

- number
- letter

I want to `SELECT` from a table in Postgres all rows that match **both the letter and the number**, according to my collection.

The `IN` query seems to be the tool for the job, but how can I make it work for *tuples* matching?

(I'm calling the pair of `(number, letter)` a *tuple* in this case)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I've searched everywhere and found no answer, maybe it is because I was searching with the wrong terms. But then I discovered the solution myself:

#### 1) Rude solution: *turn your values into strings*.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, letter || '-' || number AS tuple FROM table
) WHERE tuple IN ('T-7', 'R-2', 'T-4')
```

#### 2) Beautiful solution: *just use tuples*.

```
SELECT * FROM table)
WHERE (letter, number) IN (('T', 7), ('R', 2), ('T', 4))
```

---

### Performance

The second one seems much better, and probably is (this "Performance" section is just a waste of time, you know that), but it has shown no performance advantage in my stupid benchmarks with a small table and 4 tuples to fetch. `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` outputs follow (not the same queries of the above section):

**1) Rude:**

```
Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..3.20 rows=4 width=11) (actual time=0.037..0.156 rows=4 loops=1)
   Filter: (((name || '-'::text) || (seq)::text) = ANY ('{maria-17,antônia-33,joana-64,joana-76}'::text[]))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 194
 Total runtime: 0.183 ms
```

**2) Beautiful:**

```
Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..3.39 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.022..0.077 rows=4 loops=1)
   Filter: (((name = 'maria'::text) AND (seq = 17)) OR ((name = 'antônia'::text) AND (seq = 33)) OR ((name = 'joana'::text) AND (seq = 64)) OR ((name = 'joana'::text) AND (seq = 76)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 194
 Total runtime: 0.101 ms
```

Comment: Does the performance change if you have an index on letter, number or (letter, number)?

Comment: Well, the second version doesn't work in some DBMS. I am trying sqlite3 and it doesn't work. `Result: row value misused` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123011/sqlite-row-value-misused-error, it seems you can' put brackets around the `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Also check out this [How can I rewrite a multi-column IN clause to work on SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525779/how-can-i-rewrite-a-multi-column-in-clause-to-work-on-sqlite) solution. I used it to do the same thing in sqlite, which does not support using IN for a list of tuples.

Essentially, you create a temporary table of the pairs you want to match and then do a join select between that table and your table of interest.

Create the temporary table of pairs you're interested in checking for, as tuples:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pair (_number INTEGER, _letter TEXT);
        INSERT INTO pair (_number, _letter) VALUES ('2', 'R');
        INSERT INTO pair (_number, _letter) VALUES ('4', 'B');
        INSERT INTO pair (_number, _letter) VALUES ('7', 'R');
```

Then do the SELECT query to find the values in the original data table:

```
SELECT     my_table.*
FROM       my_table
INNER JOIN  pair
        ON pair._number = my_table.number
       AND pair._letter = my_table.letter;
```

The result is this one `-> ('2', 'R')`

Fiddle example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6f045/3

There are distinctions between the different cases for when your pairs are unique, not unique, and are not in the table.