# "Row value misused" error in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I'm getting an error from an sqlite3 query for which I can't find any reference material. Googling the string takes me deep in the SQLite code itself, and that's so opaque I can't make heads or tails of it.

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE quote (
    seqnum INTEGER,
    session STRING,
    timestamp_sip INTEGER,
    timestamp_1 INTEGER,
    market_center STRING,
    symbol STRING,
    bid_price INTEGER,
    bid_lots INTEGER,
    offer_price INTEGER,
    offer_lots INTEGER,
    flags INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (symbol, seqnum) );
```

The query:

```
select (seqnum, session, timestamp_sip, timestamp_1, market_center, symbol)
    from quote
    where symbol = 'QQQ';
```

The error:

> Error: row value misused

I have no idea how to proceed here. There is plenty of data in the table that would match the query:

```
sqlite> select count(*) from quote where symbol = 'QQQ';
2675931
```

Can anyone offer any guidance here? Sqlite version is 3.16.2.

Comment: [row values](http://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html).

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Nevermind. Those parentheses around the select columns (left over from a copy/paste) are the problem. Poor error message, maybe. But my fault.

Comment: Argh. Made exactly the same mistake during an `INSERT INTO X (c1, c2...) SELECT...` statement. This is a horrible error. And it looks like you have plenty of company.

Comment: Same issue with `ORDER BY (sections.orderId, items.orderId)`. You're answer pointed me into the right direction. :)

Answer (score 4):

JUST

```
select seqnum, session, timestamp_sip, timestamp_1, market_center, symbol
    from quote
    where symbol = 'QQQ';
```

then it works.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar when working with a Rails 5.2 Application.

For my case I was trying to write a search query for a model in application:

```
def self.search(params)
  applications = all.order('created_at DESC') # for not existing params args
  applications = applications.where("cast(id as text) like ?, email like ?, first_name like ?, last_name like ?, appref like ?", "#{params[:search]}", "%#{params[:search]}%", "#{params[:search]}", "#{params[:search]}", "#{params[:search]}",) if params[:search]
  applications
end
```

The issue was that I was using a comma (`,`) to separate the search parameters, I simply corrected by using an `OR` instead:

```
def self.search(params)
  applications = all.order('created_at DESC') # for not existing params args
  applications = applications.where("cast(id as text) like ? OR email like ? OR first_name like ? OR last_name like ? OR appref like ?", "#{params[:search]}", "%#{params[:search]}%", "#{params[:search]}", "#{params[:search]}", "#{params[:search]}",) if params[:search]
  applications
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I deleted brackets from query and it work for me: **from** SELECT (column1, column2, ...) FROM table **to** SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this bug is happing in my code, and I found this questions, but none of the answers helped me.
I fixed this problem with **remove** the **same column** in my *SELECT command*.
*(It's stupid, because I can't select the column if the column is already in the condition subcommand.)*

This is the problem SQL command **(DO NOT USE THIS)**:

```
SELECT (`id`, `username`) FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 'someone_s id'
```

This is the fixed SQL command **(PLEASE USE THIS)**:

```
SELECT (`username`) FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 'someone_s id'
```

Answer (score 1):

The same error occurs when putting the elements of a `GROUP BY` clause inside brackets, as in

```sql
SELECT 1 as a, 2 as b FROM (SELECT 1) GROUP BY (a, b);
```

The correct syntax is, of course

```sql
SELECT 1 as a, 2 as b FROM (SELECT 1) GROUP BY a, b;
```