# Select query by pair of column in where clause

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

Table Records Contain

```
Records
{
  UniqueId varchar(128),
  Key      varchar(128),
  Values   varchar(128)
};

UniqueId Key Values

2001     F    1      
2001     G    2      
2002     F    1      
2002     M    1      
2003     F    1      
2003     G    2      
2003     Z    3
```

User will give me `StringMap` of `Key` and `value`. we have to return Unique ID

User Input

```
Key value

F    1
G    2
```

My expected result is `2001` and `2003`

I'm getting below error when using below query:

```
select DISTINCT (AppId) from ApplicationCustomRecords where (Key,values) in (VALUES ('A','1'), ('C','1'))
```

> Error: near ",": syntax error Sqlite3 version - 3.7.3

Comment: I'm getting below error when using below query
select DISTINCT (AppId) from ApplicationCustomRecords where (Key,values) in (VALUES ('A','1'), ('C','1'))

Error: near ",": syntax error
Sqlite3 version - 3.7.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rewrite a multi-column IN clause to work on SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525779/how-can-i-rewrite-a-multi-column-in-clause-to-work-on-sqlite)

Comment: @forpas Yes it does. But if OP is using version 3.7.3 from *2010* it's not going to work for him because row value expression support wasn't added until a few years ago in 3.15: https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html

Comment: @Shawn then today I learned something about the (underrated) sqlite. I'm deleting the comment so it does not confuse anyone...

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about using [row values](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) works fine; the problem is that you're using a very old version of sqlite that doesn't support that feature (It was added in 3.15.0). With a more recent release:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test(key, val);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test WHERE (key, val) IN (VALUES ('A', 1), ('B', 2));
key         val       
----------  ----------
A           1         
B           2
```

So upgrade your sqlite version (Best option), or re-write the query to not use row values.

Comment: Thanks, 
I can't upgrade the sqlite version, what is the other way to do it in same version ?

Comment: Great news/answer! I had a look at other places - nobody/nowhere mentions this. Had to check it out: [Multi column IN condition](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/50494/1), works indeed! Thx!