# How to select where a data list is a subset of all columns in sqlite3 of Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, select

I have a database with 20 columns with digits, and try to find rows with specified 5 data.
try #1: Failed

```
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ('1', '15', '3', '9', '53') IN (col1, col2, ..., col20)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: row value misused
```

try #2: Pass

```
>>> c.execute("select * from mytable where '1' in (col1, col2, col3) and '15' in (col1, col2, col3)"
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00000246516AF030>
```

I cannot use the way of try #2 to work for 5 data with 20 columns, or more data and more columns. it's so stupid. Is there something like this and work ?

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ('1', '15', '3', '9', '53') IN (col1, col2, ..., col20)")
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525779/how-can-i-rewrite-a-multi-column-in-clause-to-work-on-sqlite) help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for a table with an integer primary key `id` and 8 columns: col1, col2, ....

```
with 
  list(col) as (VALUES (1), (15), (3), (9), (53)),
  cte as (
    select id, 
      ',' || col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || col3 || ',' || col4 || 
      ',' || col5 || ',' || col6 || ',' || col7 || ',' || col8 || ',' col 
    from mytable
    )  
select * from mytable
where id in (
  select c.id 
  from cte c inner join list l
  on c.col like '%,' || l.col || ',%' 
  group by c.id 
  having count(*) = (select count(*) from list)
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dzvph59WBxVahu6PgE9FE6/2).

Comment: It seems work fine, even I don't understand what it mean.